# jQuery Validation - check if a string has a unicode or space character doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Please see my code, checkUser function doesn't working. I think there is an error in value.match() function:

```
<form id="register_form" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Info</legend>

        <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
            <input type="submit" id="btnAccess" class="button" value="Submit" name="btnAccess"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $('#register_form').validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                checkUsername: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "No blank",
                minlength: "Enter atleast 4 words"
            }
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod('checkUsername', function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || !/\s/g.test(value) || !value.match(/^ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙ+/);
    },  "No space or unicode character");
});
```

You can check here http://jsfiddle.net/nambatre/rEpqr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var validator = $('#register_form').validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                checkUsername: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "No blank",
                minlength: "Enter atleast 4 words"
            }
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod('checkUsername', function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || (!/\s/g.test(value) && !/[ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙ]/.test(value));
    },  "No space or unicode character");;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Kscj/)